# AWS Cognito General Attribute settings using Cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS and I am trying to create a new user-pool in that i want to achieve the below highlighted settings to be done using Cloud Formation. can you point me in the right direction to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please based on this one to change a bit for you. This is I'm using which is very close to your requirement already.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >
  AWS CloudFormation template to create core infrastructure
Parameters:
  Product:
    Type: String
    Default: "your-product-name"
Resources:
    UserPool:
        Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
        Properties:
          UserPoolName: !Join ["-", [!Ref Product, "user-pool"]]
          AutoVerifiedAttributes:
            - email
          Schema:
            - AttributeDataType: "String"
              Mutable: true
              Name: "email"
              Required: true
            - AttributeDataType: "String"
              Mutable: true
              Name: "family_name"
              Required: true
            - AttributeDataType: "String"
              Mutable: true
              Name: "given_name"
              Required: true
          UsernameAttributes:
            - email
          AccountRecoverySetting:
            RecoveryMechanisms:
              - Name: verified_email
                Priority: 1
          AdminCreateUserConfig:
            AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: False
          UsernameConfiguration:
            CaseSensitive: false
          Policies:
            PasswordPolicy:
              MinimumLength: 6
              RequireLowercase: false
              RequireNumbers: false
              RequireSymbols: false
              RequireUppercase: false
              TemporaryPasswordValidityDays: 30
          DeviceConfiguration:
            ChallengeRequiredOnNewDevice: false
            DeviceOnlyRememberedOnUserPrompt: false
          VerificationMessageTemplate:
            DefaultEmailOption: CONFIRM_WITH_LINK
          UserPoolTags:
            product: !Ref Product
```

If you need more than that, please comment more.

Comment: Hi 
i want json for "MFA and verifications" so i am not sure exactly under which section this will come in these parameters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-mfaconfiguration

I do see MFA, but where can i do more setting related to verifications

Answer (score 1):

To set phone number as a username:

```
UsernameAttributes:
  - phone_number
```

and to set phone number as a required attribute:

```
Schema:
  - Name: email
    AttributeDataType: String
    Required: true
    Mutable: true
```

You can refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html to get the detailed information.